# How to read a file uploaded from Postman (form-data) in JAX-RS?

Tags: rest, postman, jax-rs, multipartform-data

Please refer following image of Postman

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! This is evidently a problem with your server side code. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to handle the upload. Also post any related app configuration. Without this, we have no idea what you are doing and will not be able to help.